# Connecting OpenFrameWorks with exciting project VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, linker, openframeworks, ar.drone

I want to make a awesome user interface using openframeworks for a drone project. I am using [CVDrone](https://github.com/puku0x/cvdrone) project as my base, and want to able to connect CVDrone project to my openframeworks project, so that I can call functions from CVDrone in my openframeworks project.

If I run the two projects separately, they works perfectly, no errors or anything. But can't connect them.

I have given it a go, but VS 2015 trows all kind of errors at me. Everything from libraries not found to .dll files missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options. A hacky option, but pragmatic in terms of time and experience with c++, would be to have two programs, a CVDrone and an OF one, talking to each other over sockets on the same computer. [OSC](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/ofxOsc/) makes it easy to pass arguments and not have to worry about parsing data. In terms of streaming frames, you might want to check out [spout](http://visual-society.com/2014/spout-syphon-for-windows/).

However, quickly going through the CVDrone project, and it's samples, it should be possible to integrate the project into an OpenFrameworks projects. I recommend trying [ofxCV](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv) to use OpenCV directly. You will need to swap the OpenCV 2 for the OpenCV 3 libraries (headers/dlls) though and of course the `ardrone` classes to your project.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the integrate option. We have tried this option, but it has not worked. We moved all source code from CVDrone  to OF project, but it could not find the libraries and not all files and folders were included. 

Would be really appreciated if you could explain in detail how you would do it.

Comment: I have tried this solution to merge, but it will not work. 
Is it just me or is this not a vaild solution in my case? 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to get access to a Windows machine at the moment to test it out, but I recommend trying something like this:
1. Use OF's projectGenerator-vs to generate a new project with ofxOpenCv and ofxCv addon
2. Try [adding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx) the CVDrone's project `ardrone` and `3rdparty` folders to the OF VS2015 project.
Check project can compile (.h and .cpp are handled, .lib static libs (e.g. ffmpeg/lib, pthread,etc.), otherwise double check paths and that VS can "see"/access these files.

Comment: Some tweaks may be required to ensure OpenCV2-OpenCV3 differences are handled.

Comment: We ended up splitting the project into 2 parts, where we setup RPC communication between them. There were a lot of errors we could not fix when trying to merge them. 

Thanks for your answer :)